# Nested Collection Binding

Tags: wpf, binding

I want to bind nested collection to grid panel but not sure how dynamically I can do this.

Here is my collection:

```
Public class GrandParent
{
    string name;
    Icollection<Parent> ParentCollection;
}

Public class Parent
{
    string lastname;
    Icollection<Child> ChildCollection;
}

Public class Child
{
    string name;
    int age;
}
```

I want output like this:

GrandParent.Name    Parent1.LastName    Parent2.LastName    Parent3.LastName

GP1 Children[GP1,Parent1.LastName]  Children[GP1,Parent2.LastName]  Children[GP1,Parent3.LastName]
GP2 Children[GP2,Parent1.LastName]  Children[GP2,Parent2.LastName]  Children[GP2,Parent3.LastName]

Where Parent.LastNames are static.

As of now, my viewmodel class (binding class) is like this:

```
Class viewmodel
{
    collection<string> GrandParentNames
    {
    }

    collection<string> Parent1LastNames
    {
    }

    collection<string> Parent2LastNames
    {
    }

    collection<string> Parent3LastName
    {
    }
}
```

Could anyone please suggest me better approach with this?

Comment: Whatever you're trying to achieve, I think you're headed the wrong way... What are you going to do with these collections ?

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a little vague; I don't understand exactly what you are trying to bind to... What do you mean by:

> *bind nested collection to grid panel*

I can tell you right away though, that when using nested collections of data, your best bet is always going to be using a [`HierarchicalDataTemplate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.hierarchicaldatatemplate.aspx). Here are a [couple](http://blogs.msdn.com/mikehillberg/archive/2006/10/11/a-treeview-a-hierarchicaldatatemplate-and-a-2d-collection-walk-into-a-bar.aspx) [examples](http://www.dev102.blogspot.com/2007/12/how-to-use-hierarchical-datatemplate-in.html) of using one.

Answer (score 0):

Hey Charlie, looks like I didn't put the my question well.... Sorry for the same..

My collections are nested but my output I want is not nested..

it should be like...

Parent Property I want to use for header name
GranParent Name I want o use for First Column
while Child properties I want to use for Other Columns

So Input is Grant Parent -> Parent -> Child (1 to many)

out put is

```
             --         Parent        --               Parent1
```

GrandParent.Name  --         Child of Parent        --     Child of Parent1
GrandParent1.Name --         Child of Parent      --       Child of Parent1

IF I take an example here...

Country -> Designation -> Person (Name, Age)

e.g. US - Manager - Person(A, 26)
      US - Chief ARchitect - Person (B, 28)
     UK - Manager - Person(C, 26)
      UK - Chief Architect - Person (D, 28)

```
**out put is :**
```

(Header)

Country         ---          Mangaer       ---     Chief Architect

### (R0w1)

---

US              ---           A, 26        ---    B, 28

### (R0w2)

UK              ---           C,26         ---      D, 28

would apprecitate for any of clue or code...

Answer (score 0):

I'm just going to make the assumption based of your name that your are doing this in wpf.

In your code, you had the right idea for the Model, but (assuming i understand what your aiming for) you went a little astray on the ViewModel. Because the GrandParent class has a collection of Parents, and the Parents a collection of Children, in your ViewModel you'll only need a collection of GrandParrents in your ViewModel. so your ViewModel will be closer to:

```
class ViewModel
    {
        ICollection<GrandParent> Grents;
    }
```

---

as goes your View, the easiest way I know of is through data templates. You'll have to use a list box in your grid, but you can format the list box how ever you want to get the result your looking for, this is the glory of WPF. anyway, i made a simple example here:

```
<Window.Resources>

 <local:ViewModel x:Key="ViewModelDataSource" d:IsDataSource="True"/>
 <DataTemplate x:Key="GrandParents_Data_Template">
  <StackPanel>
<TextBlock Text="{Binding name}"/>
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding ParentCollection}" ItemTemplate="{DynamicResource Parents_Data_Template}"/>
```

```
</Window.Resources>
```

Hope that helps get you going in the right direction at least. Let me know if you have any more questions.